# Nashorn – Concurrent invocations get stuck in WeekHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, nashorn

I aware that JavaScript by design won’t support multithread, but we use JavaScript code like a service, where we compile the JavaScript code using Nashorn and invoke one of the method from the compiled script instance, concurrently, with different inputs to get the desired output. Our JavaScript code is thread-safe and they never access or manipulate any global data, no closures manipulation.

Occasionally, one of the thread get stuck in WeekHashMap and blocks all other concurrent threads forever. As of now, we don’t have any workaround or solution, since the WeekHashMap::getEntry() method is get stuck in tight-loop and there is no way to interrupt and safely kill the thread. This forces us to bounce the box now and then, this also downgrades Nashorn's adoptions in Tier-1 high revenue systems.

**Thread Dump:**

```
"Thread-3" #7647 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f023c2d0800 nid=0x9384 runnable [0x00007f03feee9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.WeakHashMap.getEntry(WeakHashMap.java:431)
    at java.util.WeakHashMap.containsKey(WeakHashMap.java:417)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListeners$WeakPropertyMapSet.contains(PropertyListeners.java:217)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListeners.containsListener(PropertyListeners.java:115)
    - locked <0x000000063c9ecd68> (a jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListeners)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListeners.addListener(PropertyListeners.java:95)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyMap.addListener(PropertyMap.java:247)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.getProtoSwitchPoint(ScriptObject.java:2112)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.createEmptyGetter(ScriptObject.java:2409)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.noSuchProperty(ScriptObject.java:2353)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.findGetMethod(ScriptObject.java:1960)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.lookup(ScriptObject.java:1828)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:104)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:98)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:253)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1376533963.invokeSpecial_LLIL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/1644775282.reinvoke(LambdaForm$BMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1967400458.exactInvoker(LambdaForm$MH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$reinvoker/1083020379.dontInline(LambdaForm$reinvoker)
    //Trimmed Purposely

"Thread-2" #7646 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f023c2d6800 nid=0x9383 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f03fefea000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListeners.containsListener(PropertyListeners.java:111)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000063c9ecd68> (a jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListeners)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListeners.addListener(PropertyListeners.java:95)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyMap.addListener(PropertyMap.java:247)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.getProtoSwitchPoint(ScriptObject.java:2112)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.createEmptyGetter(ScriptObject.java:2409)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.noSuchProperty(ScriptObject.java:2353)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.findGetMethod(ScriptObject.java:1960)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.lookup(ScriptObject.java:1828)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:104)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:98)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:253)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1376533963.invokeSpecial_LLIL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/1644775282.reinvoke(LambdaForm$BMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1967400458.exactInvoker(LambdaForm$MH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$reinvoker/1083020379.dontInline(LambdaForm$reinvoker)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/363682507.guard(LambdaForm$MH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$reinvoker/1083020379.dontInline(LambdaForm$reinvoker)
    //Trimmed Purposely
```

Almost similar issue reported in the following bug, but I am not able to +1 or add more details in this bug. As stated in this bug, it is really hard to reproduce this bug from developer system. 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146274

**Questions:**

1. If there any better workaround to address this problem?
2. What if JDK team replace the WeakHashMap with ConcurrentHashMap? WeakHashMap for sure does not support thread safety.

Comment: Are you evaluating the compiled script in a separate context? Or within the script engine's default context?

Comment: I think I have a fix for the problem, but I can't really reproduce the issue. Can you provide some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @HannesWallnöfer - Nice to know that you have fix for this issue. As I stated earlier, there are no definite steps to reproduce this error. Once in few iterations, we are able to reproduce it. Also, is there any plan to reduce the thread contentions (synchronized blocks) on Nashorn internals - most of the time our throughput of single thread and multiple threads were same. For sure, we are expecting linear throughput on multi-threaded environment, is it ambitious :)